# Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908) on Fedora 32

Tags: linux, virtualbox, drivers, fedora, kernel

Running VirtualBox 6.1.12 r139181 on Fedora 32 and it is working fine. But after update to kernel 5.8.4-200.fc32.x86_64 on Fedora, I get the following error when trying to load a VM.

> The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up
> correctly. Please try setting it up again by executing
>
> '/sbin/vboxconfig'
>
> as root.
>
> If your system has EFI Secure Boot enabled you may also need to sign
> the kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before
> you can load them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for
> more information.
>
> where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The
> support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.

Comment: How did you install VirtualBox?

Comment: After downloading it from the [https://www.virtualbox.org/](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and install it using **sudo dnf install ./[PACKAGE NAME].rpm**.

Comment: same problem. But it never worked with the previous kernel. I run the config, but the compile fails deep in the bellys. Looks like 6.1.12 was compiled against an older kernel and the headers changes too much

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: This [VirtualBox Ticket](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/19644) may be of interest.  It seems this is a known problem that is being worked on.

Comment: @rickhg12hs the link shows the **Ticket #1964** is for **VirtualBox** version **6.1.10** but here I am using **6.1.12**.

Comment: @HimadriGanguly If you actually read the comments in the ticket, you will notice that several versions of VirtualBox are mentioned, including versions after your 6.1.12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is resolved in version 6.1.14 of VirtualBox.

Comment: For whoever needs to know, do `systemctl restart vboxdrv` after the upgrade, or reboot.

Comment: still have it on 6.1.22 but @anlag s trick did it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install some dependencies for vbox:

   ```sh
   sudo dnf install kernel-devel kernel-headers dkms qt5-qtx11extras  elfutils-libelf-devel zlib-devel
   ```

   If dnf is throwing some error like these packages are not found, then add the keys and try again.

   ```sh
   wget https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc && \
   sudo rpm --import oracle_vbox.asc
   ```
2. Execute `/sbin/vboxconfig` as root.
3. Now try launching the VM.

Comment: AMAZING! Thx a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

I found that by turning off UEFI Boot in the system BIOS solved the issue after running sudo /sbin/vboxconfig. This allowed VBOX to build the appropriate kernel modules.